# Scala Popup Menu

Tags: swing, scala, popup

How do I cause a popup to get shown in Scala? I have a "backdoor" but it seems pretty ugly to me:

```
val item = new MenuItem(new Action("Say Hello") {
  def apply = println("Hello World");
})
//SO FAR SO GOOD, NOW FOR THE UGLY BIT!
val popup = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu
popup.add(item.peer)
popup.setVisible(true)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing is fine, but if you'd like to hide the peer call you could create your own class:

```
class PopupMenu extends Component
{
  override lazy val peer : JPopupMenu = new JPopupMenu

  def add(item:MenuItem) : Unit = { peer.add(item.peer) }
  def setVisible(visible:Boolean) : Unit = { peer.setVisible(visible) }
  /* Create any other peer methods here */
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
val item = new MenuItem(new Action("Say Hello") {
  def apply = println("Hello World");
})

val popup = new PopupMenu
popup.add(item)
popup.setVisible(true)
```

As an alternative, you could try SQUIB (Scala's Quirky User Interface Builder). With SQUIB, the above code becomes:

```
popup(
  contents(
    menuitem(
      'text -> "Say Hello",
      actionPerformed(
        println("Hello World!")
      )
    )
  )
).setVisible(true)
```

Comment: Why is this (popup menu) not part of the standard scala swing toolkit? I must say that I've been a bit alarmed by the lack of documentation together with some pretty basic constructs. Makes me wonder whether anyone actually uses the toolkit.

Comment: oxbow, yes, people actually do use scala-swing. The lack of documentation is not terribly surprising. The cost/benefit just doesn't pan out, since most of the methods in scala-swing are simple straightforward mappings to Java Swing methods. I wouldn't consider JPopupMenu a "basic construct", and while it is a bit of a glaring oversight, please take into consideration the amount of effort involved in wrapping every possible Swing component. There are well over 100 classes in scala.swing and scala.swing.event packages.

Comment: I know this answer is two years old, but the `PopupMenu.setVisible` method is not needed. As you inherit method `Component.visible_=` you can already say `popup.visible = true`.

Answer (score 7):

I know the question is two years old, but I think it's worth updating with another answer. Here's my solution:

```
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu
import scala.swing.{ Component, MenuItem }
import scala.swing.SequentialContainer.Wrapper

object PopupMenu {
  private[PopupMenu] trait JPopupMenuMixin { def popupMenuWrapper: PopupMenu }
}

class PopupMenu extends Component with Wrapper {

  override lazy val peer: JPopupMenu = new JPopupMenu with PopupMenu.JPopupMenuMixin with SuperMixin {
    def popupMenuWrapper = PopupMenu.this
  }

  def show(invoker: Component, x: Int, y: Int): Unit = peer.show(invoker.peer, x, y)

  /* Create any other peer methods here */
}
```

Here is some sample usage code:

```
val popupMenu = new PopupMenu {
  contents += new Menu("menu 1") {
    contents += new RadioMenuItem("radio 1.1")
    contents += new RadioMenuItem("radio 1.2")
  }
  contents += new Menu("menu 2") {
    contents += new RadioMenuItem("radio 2.1")
    contents += new RadioMenuItem("radio 2.2")
  }
}
val button = new Button("Show Popup Menu")
reactions += {
  case e: ButtonClicked => popupMenu.show(button, 0, button.bounds.height)
}
listenTo(button)
```

Some things to note:

1. Use of SuperMixin class as recommended in [scala-swing-design.pdf](http://www.scala-lang.org/sid/8), in section "Guidelines for Writing Wrappers", subsection "Use the wrapper cache".
2. Mixin scala.swing.SequentialContainer.Wrapper so that I can use the `contents +=` construct so my Popup Menu code looks like other scala-swing Menu construction code.
3. While the question uses `JPopupMenu.setVisible`, I think you are going to want to wrap and use the method `JPopupMenu.show`, so you can control the location of the Popup Menu. (Just setting it to be visible puts it in the top left-hand corner of the screen for me.)