# How to add contextmenu and undo/redo functionality to a scala swing textarea

Tags: swing, scala, textarea, contextmenu, undo-redo

When creating a new TextArea with scala.swing, there is no right-click contextmenu nor an undo functionality with Ctrl + z. Ctrl + [acv] btw works well.

How can I add these essential text-editing features?

I'm on Scala 2.9.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is no support for *undo* on the Scala level and as such you'll have to do it using Swing and calling the Java API. For a tutorial on how to use [UndoManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html), see [this link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html).

For the popup menu, see this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938753/scala-popup-menu).