# Scala Swing Popup menu on ListView

Tags: swing, scala

What would be the best way of adding a mouseListener to a Scala Swing ListView that what ever item in the list is clicked on it'll create a PopupMenu with options pertaining to that specific item that is clicked on?

Am I stuck with doing this with Java style code for now or has Scala Swing evolved a bit more since 2.8.1

A bit of what I got currently and maybe I'm listening to the wrong thing and am over looking the ScalaDocs on the ListView.

```
lazy val ui = new FlowPanel {
    val listView = ListView(items) {
        renderer = Renderer(_.name)
        listenTo(this.mouse.clicks)
        reactions += {
            case e: MouseClicked => 
                // How do I determine what item was clicked?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See also answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938753/scala-popup-menu

Comment: yeah that's pretty much how I'm doing it now. However, this is the "Java Feel" I was talking about. Whatever, it works for what I'm doing. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
  lazy val ui = new FlowPanel { 
    val listView = new ListView( Seq("spam", "eggs", "ham") )
    listenTo(listView.selection)
    reactions += {
      case SelectionChanged(`listView`) => println(listView.selection.items(0))
    }
    contents += listView
  }
```

This should produce output such as

```
spam
spam
eggs
eggs
ham
ham
```

as you click on the various items. I've never done this before but I had a look at the `UIDemo` example which can be found in the `scala.swing.test` package. To read the source, if you have IntelliJ, it's as simple as clicking on the relevant object in the scala-swing.jar in External Libraries in the Projects pane.

As for PopupMenu, I don't know - it doesn't look like that one has a scala-swing wrapper in 2.9.1, but I found one on GitHub [here](https://github.com/ingoem/scala-swing/pull/11). Or you could just use the normal Swing version.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you this works exactly as shown. I also commented on that pull request in hopes it pushes anything at all on it.

Comment: And why does the event fire twice for a single selection?  Trying to figure this out...

Comment: @ZakPatterson you get one event when you select it and one when you release the mouse button over that item. So if you hold down the mouse button on "spam" then slide the pointer over "eggs" then release you will get output "spam eggs eggs".

Answer (score 0):

This is unacceptably late, but I feel compelled to offer the "java-style" solution for anyone who might be interested (leaving aside the specific details of my implementation, the essence is in the 'reactions'):

```
 val listView = new ListView[Int] {
    selection.intervalMode = ListView.IntervalMode.Single
    listData = (1 to 20).toList
    listenTo(mouse.clicks)
    reactions += {
      case m : MouseClicked if m.clicks == 2 =>
        doSomethingWith( listData(selection.anchorIndex) )
        //where doSomethingWith is your desired result of this event
    }
 }
```

Assuming single interval mode, the key to getting the list item that was just double-clicked is in simply using anchorIndex.