# Returning selected value from scala swing ListView

Tags: swing, scala

I have a scala program that collects elements from database and small GUI that offers search conditions and displays desired selection of these elements in scala swing listview. For next step in program i'd like user to select one item and by clicking a button feed it to next part.

Listview is updating just fine, i'm listening to right place for what it comes about selection but for some reason ListView.selection.items(0) is not updating when selected item changes. Whatever i choose first will stay there despite for example changing whole listview.listData of elements.

```
lazy val ui = new FlowPanel { 
val listView = new ListView( Seq("spam", "eggs", "ham") )
listenTo(listView.selection)
reactions += {
  case SelectionChanged(`listView`) => println(listView.selection.items(0))
}
contents += listView  }
```

This is something that shoud work, and very similar to what had figured out myself. This was found from [Scala Swing Popup menu on ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290290/scala-swing-popup-menu-on-listview) answers but instead of printing selected items it just continues printing the same value i choose in first place whenever my selection changes.

Is there some manual way of telling selection to update its items or whatever could make this work. I could use ComboBox, but it would be more userfriendly to show available selections on list on a scrollpane so i'd prefer finding answer to my problem.

Im using scala version 2.11.7 and swing 2.11.0

Edit: version "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.11.0-M7" in build seems to be the source of problem.

Comment: Your code works just fine on my end ([the complete code I used to test](https://gist.github.com/alextsc/a24241515128ac61322ae79ee96fa12f)). I'm on Windows 10 x64 for reference. Are you using any other dependency/version?

Comment: I have "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.11.0-M7" in my build. Windows 7 x86 on both computers i've tested this so far.

Comment: I can actually reproduce the issue with that dependency. I guess that's a bug with the library then. I'll poke around a bit.

Comment: Whoa, so fixing this might be relatively easy. I'll try building this with other version and check if that'll fix it..

Comment: Yeah it should be, was just a drop in dependency for that small sample application, however you have to see how it fits in your overall application. In general the `org.scala-lang.modules` of `scala-swing` is newer than the `org.scala-lang` version. They changed the group ID a while back to modularize things a bit more.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that .modules was newer... So far everything seems to be working with newer version as well so thank you :) I'll add version details to my question so it will be bit more informative if someone else has made same mistake as I.. would you like to post things you have here in comments as answer so i could accept it?