# Scala Swing: missing JComponent methods on Component

Tags: scala, scala-swing

I want to use the setComponentPopupMenu(). But Scala.Swing.Component doesn't seem to have all the JComponent methods although javax.swing.JComponent is referenced in the documentation. So I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ScalaSwing api is rather incomplete, but it gives you access to the underlying swing object, with `peer`. So you can do

```
 yourScalaSwingComponent.peer.setComponentPopupMenu(...)
```

You're back in java (swing) land then.

Comment: Thanks. I can now make sense of this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938753/scala-popup-menu you can make your own wrapper but you still seem to have to pimp the methods across one at a time.