# Scala Wrapper class by extending Component and with the SequentialContainer.Wrapper trait, do I have the correct understanding of traits?

Tags: swing, scala, inheritance, mixins, traits

The following code was taken from this post: [How to create Scala swing wrapper classes with SuperMixin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727586/how-to-create-scala-swing-wrapper-classes-with-supermixin)

```
import scala.swing._
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu

class PopupMenu extends Component with SequentialContainer.Wrapper {
  override lazy val peer: JPopupMenu = new JPopupMenu with SuperMixin

  def show(invoker: Component, x: Int, y: Int): Unit = peer.show(invoker.peer, x, y)
}
```

I've been trying to make custom wrappers so need to understand this, which is simple enough but since
I'm only starting to get acquainted with Scala so I'm a little unsure about traits. So what I've been hearing is that traits is like multiple inheritance and you can mix and match them?

I've drawn a diagram representing where PopupMenu sits within the whole inheritance structure. Just to clarify a few things:

1) It seems to override lazy val peer:JComponent from Component and also gets the contents property from SequentialContainer.Wrapper? (purple text) Is that right?

2) Sequential.Wrapper also has a abstract def peer: JComponent.. but this isn't the one being overriden, so it isn't used at all here?

3) What's confusing is that Component and Sequential.Wrapper have some identical properties: both of them have def publish and def subscribe (red text).. but the one that the popupMenu will use is subscribe/publish from the Component class?

4) why can't we write PopupMenu extends SequentialContainer.Wrapper with Component instead?

Hopefully that isn't too many questions at once. Help would be much appreciated, I'm a beginner to Scala..
[image: diagram representing the inheritance/trait relationship leading up to popupMenu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer using the numbers of your questions:

1. Correct
2. Correct. The top trait is `UIElement` which defines an *abstract* member `def peer: java.awt.Component`. Then you have `Container` which merely adds *abstract* member `def contents: Seq[Component]` to be able to read the child components. `Container.Wrapper` is a *concrete* implementation of `Container` which assumes (abstractly) the Java peer is a `javax.swing.JComponent`. Note that in Java's own hierarchy, `javax.swing.JComponent` is a sub-type of `java.awt.Component`, so there is no conflict. Sub-types can refine the types of their members ("covariance"). `SequentialContainer` refines `Container` by saying that `contents` is a *mutable buffer* (instead of the read-only sequence). Consequently, its *implementation* `SequentialContainer.Wrapper` mixes in `Container.Wrapper` but replaces the `contents` by a standard Scala buffer. At no point has a concrete `peer` been given, yet. For convenience, `Component` does implement that member, but then as you have seen, the final class `PopupMenu` overrides the `peer`. Because of the way the type system works, all the participating traits can access `peer`, but only `PopupMenu` "knows" that the type has been refined to be `javax.swing.JPopupMenu`. For example `SequentialContainer.Wrapper` only knows there is a `javax.swing.JComponent`, and so it can use this part of the API of the peer.
3. The `Publisher` trait is introduced by `UIElement`, so you will find it in all types deriving from `UIElement`. **There is nothing wrong with having the same trait appear multiple times in the hierarchy. In the final class, there is only one instance of `Publisher`, there do not exist multiple "versions" of it.** Even if `Publisher` had not been defined at the root, but independently in for example `Component` and `SequentialContainer.Wrapper`, you would only get one instance in the final class.
4. This is an easy one. In Scala you can only extend one class, but mix in any number of traits. `Component` is a class while all other things else are traits. It's `class A extends <trait-or-class> with <trait> with <trait> ...`.

---

To sum up, all GUI elements inherit from trait `UIElement` which is backed up by a `java.awt.Component`. Elements which have child elements use trait `Container`, and all the normal panel type elements which allow you to add and remove elements in a specific order use `SequentialContainer`. (Not all panels have a sequential order, for example `BorderPanel` does not). These are abstract interfaces, to get all the necessary implementations, you have the `.Wrapper` types. Finally to get a useable class, you have `Component` which extends `UIElement` and requires that the peer is `javax.swing.JComponent`, so it can implement all the standard functionality.

When you implement a new wrapper, you usually use `Component` and refine the `peer` type so that you can access the specific functionality of that peer (e.g. the `show` method of `JPopupMenu`).